# Track remote branch from local branch

Tags: git

By using:

```
git checkout --track origin/branch1
```

**does it matter to which local branch am I already checked out**? For example is it different to run the above when I am on local master or to another local branch? If yes what is the difference? Does `branch1 become branch of the current local branch`?

Comment: *"become branch of the current local branch?"* -- a branch is just a name for a commit. I guess your question is *"Does `branch1` points to the current local branch?"*; the answer is written in the documentation of [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---track).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your local `branch1` will be exactly like the remote one, no matter where you started.